# How to Call redirect page using php header on main web server

Tags: php

When i am testing my site on local php server using wamp the its all working fine. I am calling some of page using php file and its working fine.

```
header( "Location: http://127.0.0.1/portfoliohtml5/web.php" );
```

But when i try to load my page on main web server like

```
header( "Location: web.php" );
```

then its not working

Can you suggest me how can i access my page on main web server using PHP in my website.

Comment: Have you tried header( "Location: /portfoliohtml5/web.php" );

Comment: no i am not getting any error. its just not display my page.

Comment: i don't have portfoliohtml5 on main web server. Its on my local server. which is working fine..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

> HTTP/1.1 requires an absolute URI as argument to `Location`: including the scheme, hostname and absolute path, but some clients accept relative URIs. You can usually use `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`, `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` and `dirname()` to make an absolute URI from a relative one yourself:

```
<?php
/* Redirect to a different page in the current directory that was requested */
$host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$uri   = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
$extra = 'mypage.php';
header("Location: http://$host$uri/$extra");
exit;
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
But i have already tried this solution. But, Its not working..

Comment: @SecPro: You'll need to post more information, then. Have you checked your server's error logs? Have you looked at your HTTP headers that your browser receives?