# How to redirect a page with random string attach to the url

Tags: php, redirect

```
<?php
    $praga=rand();
    $praga=md5($praga);

    header("location: login.php?cmd=login_submit&id=$praga$praga&session=$praga$praga");
?>
```

That is my redirect code above but the funniest part is that is working perfect on localhost but doesn't work on a live server, it show nothing, any help will be appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Call redirect page using php header on main web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5358990/how-to-call-redirect-page-using-php-header-on-main-web-server)

Comment: 'it show nothing'. you mean the redirection does not happen or you get nothing where redirected to the login.php page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Guys, i found solution after a lot of search

```
$praga=rand();
$praga=md5($praga);
```

/*
header("location: login.php?cmd=login_submit&id=$praga$praga&session=$praga$praga");
*/
?>

window.location="login.php?cmd=login_submit&id=&session=";

So the above javascript code work for me